# Android active user ratio

Tags: android, google-play

I just saw some pretty strange statistics for one of my apps on google play.
Yesterday I got 81 daily device installs, and 32 daily device uninstalls, so I though my active device installs should increase in 49. But instead it decreased in 6. Can anyone explain me how statistics on google play are calculated, because I think I'm missing something huge here. Tried to google for a bit but couldn't find anything what could explain these numbers.

Comment: When you say installs, do you mean total user installs? Active user installs? Active device installs? Same question for uninstalls.

Comment: Not all of the stats get updated at the exact same time. Give it a few days, my guess is the other numbers will catch up.

Comment: thegrinner I just updated my question, maybe it would be clearer :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290555/why-google-plays-active-device-installs-not-equal-to-total-daily-device-install

Comment: I read somewhere that when such inconsistencies arise, believe the totals rather than the daily increments.  That's my own general approach to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user `A` install your app, then uninstall it, then install it again, then uninstall, then install again then your install count will be `3` but number of active installs will be just `1`.

Comment: Still it doesn't make any sense for me.. If the user installs and uninstalls like for 9 times, then install count would be 9 and uninstall count should be 8 for that crazy user. And now I got 81 installs 32 uninstalls, and i get -6 active installs for that day, still doesn't make any sense

Comment: Not sure if update counts as install and uninstall or just install. That'd explain the difference

Comment: Well there are only 13 upgrades reported that day, so it's not enough to explain how can I get -6 active installs . I guess it is some kind of google magic.